# MYSQL - Flatten Table Query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am having some issues with the below query, I was unsure as to how to modify it to give me the desired output which is detailed further below:

```
SELECT listup.NodeNumber As Node, listup.Station As Extension,
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 1 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key1',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 2 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key2',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 3 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key3',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 4 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key4',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 5 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key5',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 6 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key6',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 7 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key7',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 8 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key8',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 9 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key9',
       CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 10 THEN KeyDescription ELSE '' END AS 'Key10'
  FROM listup
ORDER BY listup.NodeNumber, listup.Station;
```

The output is as follows:

```
Node    Extension  Key1   Key2   Key3  etc.
N100    14311   14311                                    
N100    14311       14308                                
N100    14311           14309                            
N100    14311               14314                        
N100    14311                   14412                    
N100    14311                       14535                
N100    14311                           14316            
N100    14311                               14456        
N100    14312   14312                                    
N100    14312       14442                                
N100    14312           14311                            
N100    14312               14314                        
N100    14312                   14456                    
N100    14312                       14309                
N100    14312                           14308
```

I was wanting to have it all appear on one line, so flattened as such..
eg.

```
N100    14311   14311   14308   14309   14314  14412  14535  14316   14456
N100    14312   14312   14442   14311   14314  14456  14309  14308
```

Comment: @Syeda: Salutations and platitudes are worthless; a waste of screen real estate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a `GROUP BY` clause, and use the `MAX` aggregate to get the output you want:

```
  SELECT listup.NodeNumber As Node, listup.Station As Extension,
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 1 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key1',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 2 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key2',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 3 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key3',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 4 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key4',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 5 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key5',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 6 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key6',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 7 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key7',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 8 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key8',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 9 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key9',
         MAX(CASE WHEN VoiceServer = 10 THEN KeyDescription ELSE NULL END) AS 'Key10'
    FROM listup
GROUP BY listup.NodeNumber As Node, listup.Station As Extension
ORDER BY listup.NodeNumber, listup.Station
```

`NULL` is preferable to a zero length string.

Comment: OMG Ponies - words cannot express how much I'm loving you right now! I have been going absolutely crazy for so long trying to get this to work! HERO!!!!!

Comment: @Will L: You can see how close you were :)