# MySQL - How to group multiple values in different columns?

Tags: mysql

**MySQL Table:**

| id | itemid | parname | parval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000000000001 | Manufacturer Part Number | 4B0927156BL |
| 2 | 000000000001 | Unit Type | Unit |
| 3 | 000000000001 | Brand | Audi |
| 4 | 000000000002 | Type | Engine Control Unit |
| 5 | 000000000002 | Manufacturer Part Number | 8E0907401N |
| 6 | 000000000002 | Brand | Audi |

I need to group *parname* and *parval* for a distinct *itemid*, to get something like as below:

| itemid | Manufacturer Part Number | Unit Type | Brand | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000000001 | 4B0927156BL | Unit | Audi |  |
| 000000000002 | 8E0907401N |  | Audi | Engine Control Unit |

I really need help with this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The MySQL version?  What language will you be using to obtain this result?

Comment: I'm using 10.4.17-MariaDB. The PHP would be the best to get the result.

Comment: Is there a table containing all possible parname, or are the parameter names fixed?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591865/mysql-flatten-table-query) looks like it could help you :)

Comment: I have one table containing all possible parameter names and values. But for the distinct parnames, there are 11 distinct values.